# Not able to find the right technique to increase the performance of database retrieving

Tags: database, performance, indexing

I have an 2 tables from 12 tables and these 2 tables having millions of records , and when I retrieve the data from these tables it takes much more time . I have heard about indexing , but I think indexing is not a right approach which can be used here . Because each time , I need to fetch whole record instead of 2-3 columns of a record. I also applied indexing , but it took more execution time than without indexing because I fetched whole record.

So , what should be the right approach can be used here?

Comment: By which criterion do you get those 2-3 records ?

Comment: What is your tables' structure ? What is your query ?

Comment: Indexing is not something you have applied or not. Indexing needs to be appropriate too, to be of any use. The appropriate part is the tricky one and is depending on your schema and your data. You need to provide much more details about your schema and your data to make it possible for anybody to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing my arguments on Oracle, but similar principles probably apply to other RDBMSs. Please tag your question with the system used.

For indexing the number of columns is mostly irrelevant. More important is the number of rows. But I guess you need all or mostly all of those as well. Indexing won't help in this case, since it would just add another step in the process without reducing the amount of work getting done.

So what you seem to do are large table scans. Those are normally not cached, because they would basically flush the whole cache from all the other useful data being stored there. So every time you select this kind of data you have to scratch in from disc, probably sending it over a wire also. This is bound to take some time.

From what you describe probably the best approach is to cut down on disc reads and network traffic by caching the data as near as possible to the application as possible. Try to setup a cache on the machine of your application possibly as part of your application. Read the data once, put it in the cache and read it from their afterwards. An in memory database would allow you to keep your SQL based access path if this is of any value for you.

Possibly try to fill the cache in the background before anybody is trying to use it.

Of course this will eat up quite some memory and you have to judge if this is feasible.

Second approach would be to tune the caching settings to make the database cache those tables in memory. But be warned that this will affect the performance of the database as a whole and not in a positive way.

Third option might be to move your processing logic into the database. It won't reduce the amount of disc I/O, but at least you would take the network out of the loop (assuming this is part of the issue)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can try things out  :-

1. enable/increase query cache size of the database.
2. memcached at application level will increase your performance (for sure).
3. tweak your queries to get the best performance, and configure the best working indexes.

Hope it helps. I had tested all three for MySQL database - django(python) applicaton and they show good results.